# Android Java app Jsch send commands using buttons

Tags: android, jsch, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write my first every android app to connect to my Raspberry Pi and control my DSLR using gphoto2 library. I currently have a very crude app with two buttons, a "Connect" button and a "Capture" button.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import java.util.Properties;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the send button */
    public void sshConnect(View view) throws Exception {

            Properties props = new Properties(); 
            props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

            String host="123.456.7.89";
            String user ="pi";
            String pwd = "password";
            int port = 22;

            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            config.put("compression.s2c", "zlib,none");
            config.put("compression.c2s", "zlib,none");

            JSch jsch=new JSch();  
            Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, port);          
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword(pwd);
            session.connect();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Connected to Pi";
            int duration = android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            android.widget.Toast toast = android.widget.Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
    }
    public static void sendCapture(Session session) throws Exception {    
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("gphoto2 --capture-image");
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            channel.connect();

    }
}
```

I can connect to my raspberry pi but am unable to pass the jsch session to the "Capture" button without calling it from the connect section using:

```
sendCapture(session);
```

I would like the code to connect over ssh using the "Connect" button and then be able to take photos using the "capture" button as many times as possible. Any questions or general advice welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You could connect when pressing the capture button, capture & disconnect. No need to keep the connection then. And you should wrap all that in e.g. an [`AsyncTask`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: Connecting, capturing and disconnecting is the way I may have to do it. I would prefer the connection to stay open because I aim to make the app more complex and it would be easier if the connection stays open. Thanks for the AsyncTask information definitely something I should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ip,username,password;
            ip="192.168.x.x";
            username="guest";
            password="guest";
  //Write your code here 

 });
```